# PHP smarty variable error

Tags: php, variables, smarty

I have this error

> " NOTICE: UNDEFINED VARIABLE: LOGO IN C:\WAMP\WWW\SITE\TOOLS\SMARTY\SYSPLUGINS\SMARTY_INTERNAL_DATA.PHP ON LINE 291 CALL STACK"

Here is my PHP code

```
function hookFooter($params)
{
    global $smarty;
    $smarty->assign('ENT_QUOTES', ENT_QUOTES);
    if( file_exists('modules/ebbrandingfooter/logo-footer.jpg')){
        $smarty->assign('logo','modules/ebbrandingfooter/logo-footer.jpg');
    };
    $FOOTERdescription=Configuration::get('FOOTER_DESC');
    $smarty->assign('description',$FOOTERdescription );
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'ebbrandingfooter.tpl');
}
```

And Here the TPL

```
  {if $logo}<img src="{$logo}" />{/if}
  <p>{$description}</p>
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong?
THX!!!

Comment: is your if( file_exists ) condition returning true? if not, your logo var assignement would not happen, and then your TPL would be calling a non-existent logo variable. You have tried to address it in TPL by saying "if $logo" but it still is checking for a boolean... you should say if isset $logo instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify your PHP code to ensure that $logo is set, e.g:

```
function hookFooter($params)
{
    global $smarty;
    $smarty->assign('ENT_QUOTES', ENT_QUOTES);
    if( file_exists('modules/ebbrandingfooter/logo-footer.jpg')){
        $smarty->assign('logo','modules/ebbrandingfooter/logo-footer.jpg');
    } else {
        $smarty->assign('logo', null);
    }
    $FOOTERdescription=Configuration::get('FOOTER_DESC');
    $smarty->assign('description',$FOOTERdescription );
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'ebbrandingfooter.tpl');
}
```

Also note that after a `}` you don't need a semicolon.