# Smarty internal error

Tags: php, smarty

Looking through the server PHP error log has revealed that a certain type of PHP Notices comes up as the most frequent, and it has to do with Smarty. I've found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075205/php-smarty-variable-error) which seems to describe the same error, but there is actually no answer.

The notice is the following (there are different variables stated as undefined):

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: is_admin in /usr/share/php/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_data.php on line 291
```

I wonder how I can possibly debug this one since no data (like template name) is provided.

Below I'm gonna give you some idea of the code (which you can read in full detail [here](https://code.google.com/p/opencorpora/source/browse/trunk) since it's all open-source).

So there is one global smarty object which is created in a file called `header.php`, and further in the same file some global smarty variables are set, including the one from the notice above:

```
//init Smarty
require_once('Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
...
$smarty->assign('is_admin', is_admin() ? 1 : 0);
```

This `header.php` is then included in every file that needs to show some HTML by calling `$smarty->display(...)`. So I presume that in any file where the `$smarty` object is present this object has a variable called is_admin. However, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Additionally, "normal" Smarty warnings about unset variables look differently:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sent_id in /var/www/smarty_dir/templates_c/a5aab2c66c44442365a39981ba9be18e0a1f11ad.file.history.tpl.cache.php on line 123
```

Any ideas?

**Upd.**
I've read some logs and I see that such warnings seemingly arise when a user enters a page and gets 302 HTTP status. This may be due to the following code (which is placed after smarty constructor call but before the variables are assigned:

```
//cookie check
if (!is_logged() && isset($_COOKIE['auth'])) {
    if ($user_id = check_auth_cookie()) {
        if (user_login('', '', $user_id, $_COOKIE['auth'])) {
            header("Location:".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

So I guess I should move `$smarty` initialisation after this block and it is likely to help. Still I'm curious about how it relates to the issue.

Comment: In your header.php you assigning many variables, such as `is_logged`, `readonly`, `goals`, `user_permission_*`, etc. Can smarty see this variables?

Comment: Yes, at least there are no similar warnings about other variables. However, `$is_admin` is perhaps the most used one in the templates

Comment: Try to clear smarty cache by simply removing everything in smarty's cache directory.

Comment: Yes, already done this. We're gonna see if this helps.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. The issue is really in the piece of code including

```
header("Location:".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
return;
```

My error is that `return` does not act like `exit` in this case, because when you call `return` from a file which is `require`d or `incude`d into another one, you just return the control to that another file. I wasn't aware of this feature.

Answer (score -2):

`'is_admin', is_admin()` you are trying to assign the function is_admin() as a variable {$is_admin} to the Smarty template, which according to me, is impossible.

Assign the return result to a variable i.e.:

```
$var = is_admin();
$smarty->assign('is_admin', $var);
```

Comment: False. You assign the return value if is_admin().

Comment: I don't think so. Since the parentheses are present, the result of the function call should be used.

Comment: No it's possible. It would assign the value which is returned by the function, so same way you just assigned the return value to $var.

Comment: So why would an error for undefined variable will occur, if the function is declared?

Comment: Does `assign` actually assign a value to `$is_admin`, or is it creating something internal to Smarty?

Comment: I use almost the same call extensively in the code, and it goes well with a lot of other variables. According to the docs, such a call creates an internal smarty variable which then can be called as {$is_admin} from inside a template.